# Cannot connect to target STM32G0316-DISCO

Tags: stm32, st-link

I had a working STM32G0316-DISCO board, but after programming the STM31G031 I cannot connect to the MCU anymore using ST-LINK. This is because I set pin 7 and 8 to a digital input whereas pin 7 and 8 are SWDIO and SWCLK respectively as well. This messes up the communication. I tried to pull pin 8 high (which is the boot0 pin as well) when powering the board in order to force it in a different boot mode, but STM32CubeProgrammer still cannot connect to the board, reporting "Error: No STM32 target found!"

I also tried setting the program mode to "under reset" and the reset mode to "Software reset", but nothing seems to work. What I can do?

Comment: Did you find solution about the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I switched to a board with a MCU with more pins on it.

Answer (score 0):

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/303827
Program under reset is what you need to do but reset must be held using reset pin.

Comment: I tried this as well, but unfortunately this doesn't help. Anything else I can do?